# How to use passport-jwt strategy on express to protect post route

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js, passport-jwt

I am using passportJs to authenticate users on my app, I can create users, create them credentials, and they can login with no issues. For the protected routes, I'm using passport-jwt strategy, and all routes work just fine. However, I have been trying to use the same passport strategy for the route that creates those users, but no matter what I do I always get the unauthorized response 401. On the front end I use react and axios.
Here is my passport code:

```
const opts = {
        jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme("JWT"),
        secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET
    };

passport.use(
        "jwtToPostUser",
        new JWTstrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
            try {
                User.findOne({
                    where: {
                        email: jwt_payload.email
                    }
                }).then(user => {
                    if (user) {
                        console.log("user found in db in passport");
                        done(null, user);
                    } else {
                        console.log("user not found in db");
                        done(null, false);
                    }
                });
            } catch (err) {
                done(err);
            }
        })
    );
```

Here is the route to create users:

```
router.post(
    "/signup",
    passport.authenticate("jwtToPostUser", { session: false }),
    (req, res, next) => {
        console.log(req.body);

        const {
            businessname,
            username,
            firstName,
            lastName,
            phoneNumber,
            email,
            password,
            customerStatus,
            userType,
            Gooduntil
        } = req.body;

        if (password.length < 8) {
            throw "Password must be at least 8 characters";
        } else {
            User.findOne({
                where: {
                    email
                }
            }).then(user => {
                if (user) {
                    res.send("Email already exists!");
                } else {
                    const encryptedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);

                    let newUser = {
                        businessname,
                        username,
                        firstName,
                        lastName,
                        phoneNumber,
                        email,
                        password: encryptedPassword,
                        customerStatus,
                        userType,
                        Gooduntil
                    };
                    User.create(newUser)
                        .then(() => {
                            // newUser.isAdmin = true
                            delete newUser.password;
                            res.send(newUser);
                        })
                        .catch(function(err) {
                            console.log(err);
                            res.json(err);
                        });
                }
            });
        }
    }
);
```

This JWTstrategy works for all the get routes, except for this one, that creates the user.

Here is my request from the front end:

```
 addClient = async e => {

        let newUser = {
                businessname: businessname.toLowerCase(),
                firstName: firstName.toLowerCase(),
                lastName: lastName.toLowerCase(),
                email,
                username,
                password,
                phoneNumber,
                customerStatus: customerStatus.value,
                userType,
                Gooduntil
            };
            const accessString = localStorage.getItem("JWT");
            await Axios.post(
                "/auth/signup",
                {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `JWT ${accessString}`
                    }
                },
                newUser
            )
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                    this.setState({
                        loadingAxiosReq: false
                    });
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
```

This it the error I'm getting: Error: Request failed with status code 401

Does anybody know why is this happening? The only way I can make it work is by removing the passport-JWT strategy from the signup route, but that's not secure. please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was setting the header with Authorization, instead, I replaced it with jwt, now works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that you have attached your auth token on your POST request?

Comment: well, it is attached to the axios request after the url:                                            
                   headers: {
                        Authorization: `JWT ${accessString}`
                    }              and that's how I have done it with all the other requests with no issues. Am I doing it wrong? Is there any other way? I have tried without passport, just with JWT, but still getting the same 401 response